Why do pollsters bother collecting national survey numbers when only ~10 states are actually deciding the election?
Nate Silver (formerly of FiveThirthyEight) offers this helpful list of states ranked by the chance they'll end up deciding the election:

Pennsylvania, Wisconsin, Michigan, Georgia, Arizona, North Carolina, Nevada, Florida, Texas and Virginia are the only states that at least have some chance of being important. The remaining 40 states and DC are too partisan (California / Idaho) or are too small to make a dent (Alaska). Presidential voting in states like California is more or less a formality as they've been voting solid Blue since the days of Clinton. Whether Trump loses California by 10 points or 30 points doesn't matter since all 55 electoral voters always go to the winner.
So why would NYT and other pollsters waste their resources on running a "national" poll? Asking a voter in California about their voting preferences seems like a complete waste of time.


How do you know that a state is a "waste of time" if you don't check?

@JBentley look at the election results in the past 4 elections. If the Republican or Democrat candidate always lost there by at least 10 points, don't poll them again until something changes.

Such an approach would have completely failed to make any reasonable prediction of the UK's 2019 election. There were seats which had been held by Labour for ~100 years but were won by the Conservatives. If you want a robust model, you shouldn't make any assumptions.

@JBentley how many of those seats were won with at least 60% of the vote going to the Labour candidate? I'm assuming zero. You can't compare a multi-party election with razor thin margins to a two party system.

The US and the UK both have multi-party systems with 2 dominant parties, so I'm not sure what you mean exactly. The assertion was to ignore seats that were previously lost 4 times by at least 10 points. Consider for example the Bolsover seat from that link in which Labour had a 10+ point lead (often far larger than 10) in the last 19 elections since 1950 and then lost to the Conservatives. Or a near-match in Bassetlaw (10+ lead for 7 elections since 1987 except 2017 where the lead was 9.3). There are probably other examples but I haven't gone through the whole list.

Consider also that from your table you are dismissing 3 states that the model predicts have a 1% chance of tipping the election. For any one of those, you'd be wrong 1 times out of 100 if you assumed it was irrelevant. Consider also that all those 0% are rounded. These individually small probabilities will add up to something larger overall. The whole point of a model is to make as accurate of a prediction as possible. You don't achieve that by being lazy with the data.

@JBentley no Labour candidate received 60% of the vote 4 times in a row in Bolsover followed directly by a Conservative victory. But Democrats did get 60% of the Presidential vote in the past 4 elections in California.

As I said, your original assertion wasn't 60% of the vote. It was "[losing by] at least 10 points". That's the measure I compared against. And either way, my overall point stands. When you're building a model, you can't just ignore data or make assumptions. Especially when there are lots of those assumptions and small errors can compound.

@JBentley in a two party system losing by 10 points means you've received at least 55% of the vote. So to clarify: I predict there's not a single constituency in the UK where the winning party received 55%+ of the vote in 4 elections in a row and then lost all of a sudden.

You're building up a strawman and repeatedly overlooking the main thrust of my point, which is that you can't just dismiss outcomes with small (~1%) probabilities as if they are irrelevant, particularly when there are multiple of them. You've not once addressed that point. It seems to me that you've already decided the answer to the question you posted and you're not seriously interested in hearing anything opposing it.

Because national poll results and poll results from states that will not decide the election still provide information.
E.g. if California leaned Democratic by 10 points on July 1, but by August 1 leaned Democratic by only 8 points, that would give some signal about a shift in general voting intention.
Likewise with national poll numbers.
These trendlines are especially useful when following a single pollster with identical methodology across time.
Another reason is that people are simply interested in national polls and state level polls, no matter how decisive those states are predicted to be.
Finally, we can't know what states are likely to be decisive without polling all states at least occasionally.
